# "Cannot read property 'name' of null" when trying to read server name

Tags: discord, discord.js

When I do `console.log(message.guild.name)`, it works normally, giving me the name of the guild a message was said in. However, for some reason, when running that code while DMing a user, it gives me the following error:

> (node:36816) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null'

Answer (score 2):

A [DM channel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/DMChannel) isn't in a guild, so can't have a guild attached to it

You need check the `message.channel.type` property to identify what type of channel it is. A message can come from any of these channel types [`TextChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel) (aka a guild text channel), [`DMChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/DMChannel) or [`GroupDMChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GroupDMChannel)

When looking at `channel.type` it'll give you one of the following options:

- `dm` - a DM channel
- `group` - a Group DM channel
- `text` - a guild text channel
- `voice` - a guild voice channel
- `category` - a guild category channel

The way you could do this is:

```js
switch (message.channel.type) {
    case 'text':
        // Do guild stuff
        break;

    case 'dm':
    case 'group':
        // Do DM stuff
        break;

    default:
        // Do stuff on unexpected channel
        break;
}
```